# Profiling tool on Linux showing size of parameters passed to invoked functions

Tags: linux, profiling, profiler

Can any of profiling (performance measure) tools on Linux (OProfile, perf events, HTC Toolkit) show call graph with **size of parameters** (data size) passed to function / procedure?

In other words I'd like to visualize data flow in a profiled application (best together with profile data, i.e. time spent in a function / subroutine).

---

*Note*: when arrays (vectors and matrices) are passed to subroutine / function, I am interested not only in size of pointer, but size of the whole data.

Comment: what would you define as the size of parameters passed? Would you mean just the pointer size for reference/pointer types? Would you include params passed in registers? Would you include va_args? In other words, would you be able to come up with a definition results in meaningful data? I have a hunch that simple stack size monitoring is going to be the most meaningful metric there

Comment: For pointers (arrays) I am interested not only in size of pointer, but also in size of array (of referenced structure).

Comment: IMHO that's the start of insanity; how would you deal with polymorphic structs? Are you willing to use rtti just to measure the size of referenced memory? If an array was malloced, you'd have to be an intrusive profiler to even be able to know that. If you are using smart pointers of any kind (including e.g. _`tr1::cref`_, you'll get skewed numbers); Optimization will provide other surprises. Thinking out of the box, I think callgrind/kcachegrind with some other measure than Instruction Fetch might come near _'a metric'_ in that direction, if you'd accept _actual_ mem accesses

Comment: I just ran into [`elfsh`](http://elfsh.asgardlabs.org) which boasts dynamic, interactive instrumentation of binaries on several platforms (so it would be like valgrind, but customizing); from the presentation [here](http://www.eresi-project.org/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/EKO2008_ERESI_slides.pdf) I get the impression that it should be able to use this for your purpose. It's no free lunch, as expected :) http://www.eresi-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

Beyond my skeptic remarks, I have a growing sense that you really want to have a metric that represents 'memory bandwidth', correlated to certain parts of your code.

I have a hunch that you might get mileage out of oprofile. `oprof_start` gui has a nice checklist of metrics

http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/intel-p6-mobile-events.php

(NOTE: these are CPU dependent, see http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/ or `op_help` for details on your CPU)

These seem interesting:

```
DATA_MEM_REFS    all memory references, cachable and non
L2_LD        number of L2 data loads
L2_ST        number of L2 data stores
perhaps some more, but I grew tired of reading things outside my area of expertise here
```

I think that `perf` superseeds(?) oprofile, and it certainly has the easier interface to do (sampling) call graph profiling but I guess that if you want access to actual CPU performance counter events, oprofile may still be the place to go